# Randomly sample string from list of string in a foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach, random-numbers

I have a list of strings `{happiness, only, real, when, shared}` and would like to sample from this list inside a `\foreach`.

Even though this is a very simple problem, I can't find any solution online.

Any idea?

Comment: As a non-native speaker – what does it mean “to sample from a list”? And is there a reason you tagged your question with [tag:tikz-pgf], [tag:pgfplots], and [tag:random-numbers]?

Comment: I meant 'randomly sample'. You have a list of 5 strings and at each iteration you randomly select one of them.

Comment: This is important information and you should probably edit the question to make this point more explicit.

Comment: I added it to the title of the question. Thank you for your contribution to making the question clearer. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to use `\foreach` from the [pgffor](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) package.

From the question is is not really what you want to do with this list. If you just want to loop over it a simple `\foraech` loop will work:

```
\foreach \x in {happiness, only, real, when, shared} { \x }
```

If you have the list stored in a macro, say `\states`, then that works in exactly the same way:

```
\foreach \x in \states { \x }
```

On the other hand, if you want to pick a random element of your list then you should declare it as a random list using:

```
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{states}{{happiness}{only}{real}{when}{shared}}
```

You can now randomly access the elements in the list using `\pgfmathrandomitem`. The only difference here is that `\pgfmathrandomitem` stores its output into a macro, so you need to use something like

```
\pgfmathrandomitem{\state}{states}\state
```

You can then use `\state` in all of the ways above.

Here is a full MWE that demonstrates all of these approaches:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}

  \foreach \x in {happiness, only, real, when, shared} { \x }

  \newcommand\states{happiness, only, real, when, shared}

  \foreach \x in \states { \x }

  \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{states}{{happiness}{only}{real}{when}{shared}}

  \pgfmathrandomitem{\state}{states}\state

  \foreach \x in {1,...,5} {\pgfmathrandomitem{\state}{states}\state\space}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple l3 version. The important part is the last one with `\clist_item`, because that's generating a random item from the list.

[image: mapped]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l__valentin_my_clist
\clist_set:Nn \l__valentin_my_clist {happiness, only, real, when, shared}
\cs_set:Npn \__valentin_mapper #1 {
    \noindent Argument:~#1\\
}
\clist_map_function:NN \l__valentin_my_clist \__valentin_mapper
\clist_item:Nn \l__valentin_my_clist {\fp_eval:n {randint(1,\clist_count:N \l__valentin_my_clist)}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```